# отправка письма с своего сайта с данными пользователя в форме обратной связи

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

Запускаю свой сайт. Есть форма регистрации и обратного звонка. Хочу что бы приходило письмо на мою почту с данными пользователя который ввел свои данные. На данный момент сделано на php с помощью mail(). 
1) Есть ли другие способы ? Какие? Где прочитать?
2) Как стилизовать поступающее сообщение?

Спасибо!

Comment: А чем вас не устраивает mail?

Comment: Да в принципе к mail нет претензий, но хочу ещё варианты попробовать.
на данный момент есть вопросы со стилизацией письма и с попаданием писем в спам

Answer (score 1):

Использовать внешний SMTP сервис например гугл, маилру, яндекс и т.д.

Описано как отправлять

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14456673/sending-email-with-php-from-an-smtp-server